# Custom Python Monte Carlo integration function is underestimating multi-dimensional integrals

Tags: numpy, probability, numerical-methods, montecarlo, numerical-integration

I need to create a custom Monte Carlo integration function to adapt to custom multi-dimensional distribution objects using NumPy. I need it to integrate over the same values in each dimension. It works correctly for a single dimension, but underestimates in multiple dimensions, which gets worse with higher dimensions. I am using this [paper](http://www.acclab.helsinki.fi/%7Eknordlun/mc/mc5nc.pdf) (equation 5) as a guide. Is my equation of Volume * Mean Density incorrect? Is my sampling method incorrect? I'm really at a loss for what the error is.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# Set up distribution parameters.
dim = 3
loc = np.repeat(0., repeats=dim)
scale = np.repeat(1., repeats=dim)

# Initialize a multivariate normal distribution.
mvn = multivariate_normal(mean=loc, cov=scale)

def mc_integrator(distribution, dim, support, size=1000, seed=0):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    distribution : function
        A probability density function.
    dim : int
        The number of dimensions of the distribution.
    support : list
        List of the low and high values of the hypercube to integrate over.
    size : int, optional
        Number of samples used for estimation. The default is 1000.
    seed : int, optional
        A random seed for reproducibility. The default is 0.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        The estimate of the integral over the hypercube.
    """
    # Set the random seed.
    np.random.seed(seed)
    # Separate the elements of the support.
    a, b = support[0], support[1]
    # Calculate the volume of the hypercube.
    volume = (b-a)**dim
    # Generate random samples of the appropriate shape.
    samples = np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=(size,dim))
    # Return the estimate of the integral.
    return volume*np.mean(distribution(samples))

# Set the number of samples to use for estimation.
size = 10000
# Set the low and high value over each dimension of the hypercube.
support = [-2, 2]
# Print the estimate of the integral.
print(mc_integrator(mvn.pdf, dim, support, size=size))
# Print the exact value of the integral.
print(mvn.cdf(np.repeat(support[1], dim))-mvn.cdf(np.repeat(support[0], dim)))

Output: 0.8523870204938726
        0.9332787601629401
```

Comment: 10000 samples is pretty low for MCI.

Comment: With 1,000,000 samples it is only 0.8694640813906446, so still an underestimate. It always seems to underestimate and MC should sometimes be above the true value as well. The underestimation issues gets worse as you increase the dimensions of the distribution, so it must be something with how I handle the multiple dimensions. Edit: Once I get the naïve MC integration working, I'm going to add the option of using the Halton sequence for generating samples, which would reduce the number of samples needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John, looks good overall but it looks to me that you're figuring the expected result incorrectly. I think the expected result should be `(F(2) - F(-2)^3` where `F` is the Gaussian cdf for mean 0 and variance 1. For `F(2) - F(-2)`, I get `erf(sqrt(2))` which is approximately 0.9545, and then `(F(2) - F(-2))^3` is 0.8696, which agrees pretty well with your results.

I don't know what `mvn.cdf` is supposed to return, but the concept of "cdf" is a little fishy in more than one dimension, so maybe you can steer away from that.

About multidimensional integration in general, you mention using Halton sequences. I think that's an interesting idea too. My experience with computing integrals is to use quadrature rules in 1 or 2 dimensions, low-discrepancy sequences in 3 to several (5? 7? I dunno), and MC in more than that. Oh, and also my advice is to work pretty hard for exact results before resorting to numerical approximations.

I would be interested to hear about what you're working on.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was assuming the way I used the multivariate_normal.cdf() was working in the same was as (F[b] - F[a])^# of dimensions. Unfortunately, I cannot work with quadrature rules because I have to work with very high dimensional distributions, so the run times blow up. I am building functions to work with coupled distributions and calculate coupled entropy, cross-entropy, and divergences. Finding exact results is tricky and using numerical approximations allows me to get approximate results for any distribution.